# redirect all requests starting with 0x to index.html

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My website will be like `example.com/0xETHEREUMADDRESS`.

So i want to redirect all those request starting with `0x` to `INDEX.HTML` and `index.html` has already the code to the rest of work.

I need `.htaccess` code to redirect all starting with `0x` to `index.html`.
Here is my tried .htaccess rules file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule (0x*)$ /index.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Do you really want a "redirect"? You want the user to see `/index.html` in the URL and the original URL that starts `Ox` will be lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
> RewriteRule (0x*)$ /index.html [L,R=302]
> ```

The regex `(0x*)$` matches URLs that *end-with* `0`, `0x`, `0xx`, `0xxx` etc. It does not match URLs that start-with `0x`, so this will not match the desired URL. The `*` character is a regex quantifier that repeats the preceding token 0 or more times. There is also no need for the capturing group (surrounding parentheses).

If the rule only matches URLs that start with `Ox` then the *condition* that checks the URL is *not* `/index.html` is therefore redundant.

The following will do what you are asking:

```
RewriteRule ^0x /index.html [R=302,L]
```

The `^` is the start-of-string anchor, so the requested URL must start with `0x`. Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.

However, I'd question whether you really want to "redirect" the user? (As in an external HTTP redirect - which is what this is.) Redirecting will lose the original URL and expose `/index.html` to your users.

#### Internal "rewrite" instead

If, however, you wish to *internally rewrite* the request instead so that `index.html` can analyse the requested URL (as you say, "`index.html` has already the code to the rest of work") and keep `/0xETHEREUMADDRESS` in the browser's address bar then remove the `R=302` flag and the slash prefix on the *substitution* string. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^0x index.html [L]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex

Comment: RewriteRule ^0x /index.html [R=302,L] is redirecting to index.html... i dont want redirect

Comment: @heustfdgehsgd (Except that is what you were asking for.) Read my last paragraph.

Comment: @heustfdgehsgd I've updated my answer with a bit more info and an example of the internal "rewrite".